# Boruta box plots in R

Tags: r, boxplot, feature-selection

I'm doing variable selection with the Boruta package in R. Boruta gives me the standard series of boxplots in a single graph, which is useful, but given the fact that I have too many predictors, I am hoping to be able to limit the number of boxplots that appear in the boruta plot.  Something like the following image.

[image: Boruta plot]

Basicacly, I want to "zoom" on the right end of the plot, but have no idea how to do that with the boruta plot object.

Thanks,

MR

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like an simple question, the solution seems surprisingly convoluted. Perhaps somebody can come up with a quicker/more elegant way...

Here, I create a new function based on the source function `plot.Boruta`, and add a function argument `pars` that takes the names of variables/predictors that we'd like to include in the plot.

As an example, I use the `iris` dataset to fit a model.

```
# Fit model to the iris dataset
library(Boruta);
fit <- Boruta(Species ~ ., data = iris, doTrace = 2);
```

The function `generateCol` is internally called by `plot.Boruta`, but is not exported and therefore not available outside of the package. However, we need the function for our revised `plot.Boruta` routine.

```
# generateCol is needed by plot.Boruta
generateCol<-function(x,colCode,col,numShadow){
 #Checking arguments
 if(is.null(col) & length(colCode)!=4)
  stop('colCode should have 4 elements.');
 #Generating col
 if(is.null(col)){
  rep(colCode[4],length(x$finalDecision)+numShadow)->cc;
  cc[c(x$finalDecision=='Confirmed',rep(FALSE,numShadow))]<-colCode[1];
  cc[c(x$finalDecision=='Tentative',rep(FALSE,numShadow))]<-colCode[2];
  cc[c(x$finalDecision=='Rejected',rep(FALSE,numShadow))]<-colCode[3];
  col=cc;
 }
 return(col);
}
```

We now modify `plot.Boruta`, and add a function parameter `pars`, by which we filter our list of variables.

```
# Modified plot.Boruta
plot.Boruta.sel <- function(
    x,
    pars = NULL,
    colCode = c('green','yellow','red','blue'),
    sort = TRUE,
    whichShadow = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE),
    col = NULL, xlab = 'Attributes', ylab = 'Importance', ...) {

    #Checking arguments
    if(class(x)!='Boruta')
        stop('This function needs Boruta object as an argument.');
    if(is.null(x$ImpHistory))
        stop('Importance history was not stored during the Boruta run.');

    #Removal of -Infs and conversion to a list
    lz <- lapply(1:ncol(x$ImpHistory), function(i)
        x$ImpHistory[is.finite(x$ImpHistory[,i]),i]);
    colnames(x$ImpHistory)->names(lz);

    #Selection of shadow meta-attributes
    numShadow <- sum(whichShadow);
    lz <- lz[c(rep(TRUE,length(x$finalDecision)), whichShadow)];

    #Generating color vector
    col <- generateCol(x, colCode, col, numShadow);

    #Ordering boxes due to attribute median importance
    if (sort) {
        ii <- order(sapply(lz, stats::median));
        lz <- lz[ii];
        col <- col[ii];
    }

    # Select parameters of interest
    if (!is.null(pars)) lz <- lz[names(lz) %in% pars];

    #Final plotting
    graphics::boxplot(lz, xlab = xlab, ylab = ylab, col = col, ...);
    invisible(x);
}
```

Now all we need to do is call `plot.Boruta.sel` instead of `plot`, and specify the variables that we'd like to include.

```
plot.Boruta.sel(fit, pars = c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width"));
```

[image]

Comment: Wow.  Thanks a lot.  That was quite a lot of effort put into this answer.  I really appreciate it.  Hopefully others with the same question will benefit in the future. Again many thanks.

Comment: No worries @MarioReyes . Glad to help.

Comment: Thank you!!! Great effort! But why the Sepal.Width and Sepal.Length in the graph above came blue whereas in "full" Boruta fit they are green???

Comment: It is only a matter of color choice @AussieAndy, you can choose your preferred color  in the very last part of the function:

    `#Final plotting
        graphics::boxplot(lz, xlab = xlab, ylab = ylab, col = col, ...);
        invisible(x);`

So you can select a green color by setting `col = "g"`

Comment: Yes, this is true, but the problem is the Boruta algorithm by default assigning green to "important" variables, yellow to "tentatively important", red to "non-important" and blue to "shadow MIN", "shadow MEAN" and "shadow MAX". It would be great if this code above could take the "original" colour into consideration. One might not always want to "magnify" top end (i.e. only "green") box-plots... The code above has #Generating col vector, but it is obviously not getting correct values from the "original" plot.

Comment: How can I convert the Boruta object to a data frame?

Comment: @Derelict A `data.frame` of what specifically?

Comment: @MauritsEvers I was looking to convert the entire output into a DF. I found a solution, not ideal but it works.